# Phalconphp binding view with ajax using volt template

Tags: ajax, phalcon, volt

I am using Phalcon framework, I have a controller 'Post' with action 'like':

views/layouts/post.volt

> {% for post in posts %}
>
> <h1> {{ post.content }} <⁄h1>
>
> <h2> {{ post.like }} <⁄h2>
>
> <a href="#" onclick="like();" data-id="{{ post.id }}" >Like<⁄a>
>
> {% endfor %}
>
> <!-- -->
>
> <script>
>
> ```
>    var like = function() {
>
>        var id = /* ... */; // get id of post which raise 'like' event
>
>        $.ajax({
>
>            dataType: 'json',
>
>            url: 'post/like/' + id
>
>        }).done(function() {
>
>            /* Do something meaningful */
>
>        });
> ```
>
> <⁄script>

controllers/PostController.php

> /* ... */
>
> public function indexAction() {
>
> ```
>    $this->view->posts = /* ... */; // read from database to show the view
> ```
>
> }
>
> public function likeAction($id) {
>
> ```
>    // change 'like' of corresponding post with certain 'id'
>
>    foreach($this->view->posts as post) {
>
>        if($post->id == $id) $post->like += 1;
>
>        /* ... */
>
>    }
>
>    // write to database, and re-render entire post view
>
>    $this->view->posts = /* ... */; 
>
>        // I just assign 'view' again and hope it works :(
>
>    $result = array('msg' => 'success');
>
>    $response = new Response();
>
>    return $response->setJsonContent($result);
> ```
>
> }
>
> /* ... */

But after clicking the button, nothing has changed! Did I do something wrong? Can anyone help me... Thank in advance!

P/S: sorry for my bad English... ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'$this->view->posts' is set only in 'indexAction'.
It is empty when when 'likeAction'.

Comment: Is there any way to deal with? I just want to change the view. Do I have to reload entire page, or change 'post.like' mannually by javascript after capturing the responsed data from ajax?

Comment: [This Code is update for database](http://pastebin.com/jM9vsk1g).
If need you update to page, update with javascript on after AJAX success.